# Cilk error expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token

Tags: for-loop, cilk

I try to compile a programme using cilk but it don't works

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fcilkplus -lcilkrts -ldl -O2 src/cpp/* -o bin/exe 

src/cpp/sous_monoide.cpp: Dans la fonction 
src/cpp/sous_monoide.cpp:269:19: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
cilk_for (i = 0; i < limite; i++){
               ^
src/cpp/sous_monoide.cpp:269:36: erreur : expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
cilk_for (i = 0; i < limite; i++){
                                ^
src/cpp/sous_monoide.cpp:312:1: erreur : expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^
src/cpp/sous_monoide.cpp:312:1: erreur : expected ‘}’ at end of input
src/cpp/sous_monoide.cpp:312:1: erreur : expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

This is the code :

```
const int limite = n-1;
int i;
cilk_for (i = 0; i < limite; i++){
  ....
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the  [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522593) a bit more! If you're compiling C++ and not C, which it looks like you are, the variable for the control variable needs to be defined in the cilk_for statement. So you can't use:

```
int i;
cilk_for (i =..........
```

You have to use:

```
cilk_for (int i = 0....
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include cilk/cilk.h ?

```
#include <cilk/cilk.h>
```

***cilk_for*** is defined in this header file.
Alternatively, you can use ***_Cilk_for*** without including the header.